# What are Best Practices for Property Declaration in a Custom ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

In my new UserViewModel that I'm building for my application, I have two options for storing properties.

The first option is to have

```
Public Property user As User              ''# Including the entire User object
Public Property custString as String      ''# Custom String for View
```

The second option is to actually write out all the User properties

```
Public Property ID As Integer             ''# Declaring each object individually
Public Property UserName As String        ''# Here is another object found in User
Public Property RegistrationDate As Date  ''# Here is another object found in User
Public Property custStrin As String       ''# Custom String for View
```

Can anyone tell me what the better way to do this is and why?

I've currently got the first option, however, I don't like the way it looks in the View in comparison to the second option

**This looks nice** (IMO)

```
<%: Model.UserName %>
```

**This does not look as nice** (IMO)

```
<%: Model.User.UserName %>
```

Comment: I think you meant from `<%: Modal.User.UserName %>` to `<%: Modal.UserName %>`?

Comment: No @Ahmad. I've currently got the first option in my ViewModal. This is why I had to change the code to modal.user.username - and it just looks stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think either way is "better", it really depends on the objects themselves.

If the `User` object has get-only properties, no public default constructor, or complex state logic, it might not be a good candidate to be directly set by the default model binding.  Usually in cases like that, you would "write out" some subset of the `User` properties as corresponding properties of the ViewModel, which can then handle the setup of the underlying User object.  This scenario isn't uncommon.

But if your `User` object is simple and is straightforward to bind to directly, then it's certainly more convenient to use it as part of your model directly.